# Why does the PSD2 have an exception that requires two-factor authentication only every 90 days?

Tags: authentication, banks

PSD2 requires two-factor authentication, which they call strong customer authentication (SCA). However, there is a “delegated regulation” [2018/389, Article 10](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32018R0389&from=EN#d1e661-23-1), which adds an exception that SCA is not required to view account information, specifically the account balance and transactions from the last 90 days.

That article also has an exception to the exception stating:

> 2. For the purpose of paragraph 1, payment service providers shall not be exempted from the application of strong customer authentication where either of the following condition is met:
>
>    […]
>
>    (b) more than 90 days have elapsed since the last time the payment service user accessed online the information specified in paragraph 1(b) and strong customer authentication was applied.

**I would like to know how requiring SCA every 90 days improves security over not requiring SCA at all**, at least for viewing account information.

---

As an example, for my bank, this means that the login to their online banking requires the second factor every 90 days. They even show a notification before the 90 days have expired so I can re-start the 90-day period early, which means that my account is always “activated”. This does not [seem to be very uncommon, at least in Germany](https://finanz-szene.de/digital-banking/die-psd2-strategien-aller-grossen-deutschen-banken/).

In fact, I feel this lessens security because the ChipTAN device that is my second factor only shows a cryptic “start code”, so I'm not sure if the action I'm authenticating is in fact a renewal of the 90-day period or something else. For example, when accessing transactions older than 90 days, I get the same “start code” prompt.

Comment: Doesn't the "90 days no 2FA" only apply to access made from the same terminal?  All similar systems I have seen *always* demand 2FA if logging in from a new terminal.

Comment: @BenVoigt Nope, at least my bank doesn't. I've found a description of this at https://blog.fscom.co.uk/strong-customer-authentication-the-exemptions (“Payment account information (Article 10)”), but I have no idea where to find this Article 10, e. g. in the PSD2 text at http://data.europa.eu/eli/dir/2015/2366/oj

Comment: @wrtlprnft: See the link in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:**

- If the bank is requiring 2FA every 90 days for login only, but requires it for every payment (see exceptions below, e.g. recurrent payments to the same receiver), then your bank seems to seek for balance between security and friendliness, and seems to be **compliant** with PSD2.
- If the bank requires 2FA once every 90 days also *for payments*, then this very probably **violates** the PSD2 requirements and *does not* improve security.

**Details:**

The [PSD2](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32018R0389&from=EN) defines what operations have higher risks and need a *"strong customer authentication"*.

> Where payment service  providers apply strong customer authentication
> in  accordance with  Article  97(1)  of Directive (EU)  2015/2366, the
> authentication shall  be  based on  two  or  more  elements which  are
> categorised  as knowledge, possession and inherence and shall result
> in the generation of an authentication code.

To put it simple, *"strong customer authentication"* is a multi-factor authentication, 2FA or stronger.

Mainly, this *"strong customer authentication"* is applicable to payments:

> The  requirements of  strong customer  authentication apply  to
> payments initiated  by  the  payer...

More security often means less friendliness and worse user experience. The PSD2 tries to find a balance.

> ... exemptions  to  the  principle of  strong customer authentication
> have been defined based on the level of risk, amount, recurrence and
> the payment channel used for the execution of the payment transaction.

Try to travel to Afghanistan or Marocco and login to your account. Very probably you will be asked for 2FA. Why? Because the rule above was applied: You are using other channel that has higher risk compared to access from your country.

The rule above defines basic principles. Briefly: risk estimation should take into account many different factors.

The PSD2 defines also exceptions. For instance:

> Actions which imply access to the balance and the recent transactions
> of a payment account without disclosure of  sensitive payment data,
> recurring  payments to  the  same  payees  which  have  been
> previously set  up  or confirmed by the payer through the use of
> strong customer authentication, and payments to and from the same
> natural or  legal  person with  accounts with  the  same  payment
> service  provider,  pose  a  low  level  of  risk,  thus allowing
> payment service  providers not  to  apply strong customer
> authentication.

This means that if you only login to your account and don't do any payments, your bank *is not required* to apply *"strong customer authentication"*. Some banks require 2FA also for login. Your bank uses this formal right not to do that.

One of factors for such decision may be recurrence. Try to login 1000 times a day, even without doing any payments. I would suppose that your bank will require 2FA not after 90 days, but very shortly, after you have reached some number of logins that your bunk considers as suspicious.

The requirement mentioned above allows to see *the recent transactions* without *"strong customer authentication"*. When you want to see your history older than 90 days your bank considers this as not recent transactions and, according to this rule, requires *"strong customer authentication"*, in your case it requires 2FA.

Requiring 2FA every 90 days is not a requirement of PSD2, but decision of your bank. The security benefits of doing that are very small. An attacker that knows your PIN will just use it between these dates, and let say will add 10 days before and 10  days after the date when the next 2FA may be requested, and use your PIN 70 days freely. The only security benefit I see is that when the bank is asking for 2FA they can be sure that the TAN device is not stolen and you still have it. The banks that want to have balance between security and user experience ask for a 2nd factor not in a *regular* interval, but at some *unpredictable* moments. Thus the attacker would not benefit from knowing that the bank asks for the 2nd factor only once every 90 days. I suppose your bank does not consider that as a risk.

Comment: They only force 2-factor authentication every 90 days, when viewing transactions older than 90 days or when ordering an actual bank transfer. I don't think my bank is blatantly violating the PSD2 by doing this, so I don't agree with your edit to my question's title.

Comment: @wrtlprnft: The new title seems accurate whether it is conformant to regulations or not.

Comment: @wrtlprnft: Sorry that my answer was too short and that I have not explained the reason to change the title. Now I have extended the answer. To the title: **PSD2 does not have requirement** to ask for 2FA only once every 90 days. Why? Because PSD2 is seeking for balance between security and friendliness. See details in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (I didn't downvote, by the way). See my edit, I think the 2FA-every-90-day rule is not a specific invention of my bank, but rather the minimum required by the PSD2. Most of the other 2FA triggers you mention (foreign IPs, excessive logins, randomness) seem to be rather easy to circumvent or to just retry later. I guess protection of unused accounts and where the user has lost their TAN device is a good thing, but can this really be the only reason for the 90-day rule? I still don't see how this is a balance because it has almost none of the security benefits of 2FA.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, mentallurg's title is a valid question, however not the one I intended to ask. I'm not surprised that some banks will do the minimum to be compliant with new regulations, but I really wonder if there is some merit to this 90-day requirement vs. no SCA at all that I'm not (yet) seeing.

Comment: @wrtlprnft: According to PS2, just logging in and viewing the recent transactions is not a high risk and 2FA (to offer more friendliness) is not required (but many banks do use 2FA even for login). Thus even asking for 2FA every 90 days is actually *nor required*. It is kind of a step from friendliness towards a bit more security.

Comment: But then I don't understand what 2018/389, Article 10 actually refers to. I was under the impression that this is the one that declares that viewing recent transactions requires no SCA, except if the last SCA happened more than 90 days ago.

Comment: @wrtlprnft: Article 10 contains of two parts. Part 1 defines exceptions, cases when banks "... shall be allowed not to apply ..." SCA. Your bank uses it and requests SCA only when you want to see transactions older than 90 days.
Part 2 defines the limits of these exceptions. For instance, if you have not used your account for 100 days and you only want to see the recent transactions, then despite the exception in part 1 allows no to require SCA for such operation, the part 2 says that 100 days are longer than allowed 90 -> an exception is not allowed -> the bank must require SCA.

Comment: Don't your two most recent comments contradict each other? Asking for 2FA *is* required every 90 days, although of course it's allowed to ask for 2FA more often, ideally every time. But the 90 days are not an invention of my bank, and I wonder why such a (from my point of view) pointless rule exists. There are benefits for unused accounts or misplaced TAN devices, but as you've said in your answer, these are rather small.